# Why result of pyserial readlines, when no new data, is not empty list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial, empty-list

I met some problem with pyserial (v3.4) readlines function.

when I run some test codes in IDLE of python 3.5

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('com4', timeout=1)
>>> a = ser.readlines()
>>> a
[]
```

but when I use the compare "is []", it give me a False

```
>>> a is []
False
```

and when I use the compare "== []", it give me a True

```
>>> a == []
True
```

I don't understand why that can happen. Is there any way to fix this, or not?

If you could, please help me with this problem.

Thank you very much.

---

Thank for Jim Fasarakis Hilliard, I have known how to edit the code and make it beautiful in PIP8. I edit and add new code for someone who meet the same problem with me

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('com4', timeout=1)
>>> a = ser.readlines()
>>> if not a:
        DO SOMETHING WHAT YOU WANT
```

Comment: thank you for your fast rely, but I cannot accept your answer.

Comment: Because readlines return the empty list [], but why "[] is []" get a False?
I use pycharm IDE and it give me notice about this compare (PIP8). And I really want to know how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Jim Fasarakis Hilliard:
"Why does “[] is [ ]” evaluate to False in python"
I think this is what I need to know :D thank you very much.
I cannot vote for you but really thank you again